# How to separately logging JBoss server specific logs with JBoss Logging and application specific logs with log4j?

Tags: java, jboss, slf4j, jboss-eap-6, jboss-logging

We're working on a migration of our application from WebSphere to JBoss EAP 6.4. I read on the Internet that since JBoss EAP 6.x, JBoss use its own logging framework called JBoss Logging instead of log4j previously.

We have already a log4j.properties file for application specific logs, which store logs in separate files according the log level (log-error.log, log-info.log, ...), but actually, they are also logged in the console and in the server.log file.

**In the one hand**, we would like application logs to be logged only with our existing log4j.properties configuration file, but also prevent them to be logged in server.log and console too.

**In the other hand**, we would like server specific logs to be logged with JBoss Logging framework, so in the server.log and in the console.

To sum up, we want to go from :

```
application logs + server logs => server.log/console + separate file logs
```

To this :

```
application logs => seperate file logs
server logs => server.log/console
```

Does somebody know how to achieve this ? 
Does anyone have already configured a JBoss server in a similar way ?

Thanks you,

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Don't understand why but log4j also logs in stdout so JBoss Logging catch these logs and appends them again to JBoss console and server.log like this :

`2017-08-08 15:14:20,304 INFO  [stdout] <<My log4j log message>>`.

I succeeded for the moment to prevent this by adding that code to **standalone.xml** file :

```
<logger category="stdout" use-parent-handlers="false">
    <level name="OFF"/>
</logger>
```

Isn't this a bad practise ?

Thanks,

Comment: If anything writes to `System.out` then it won't be logged. That would be the only issue.

Comment: Don't think it will be a problem, use of System.out is pretty discouraged in our application, but in case of, do you think I can declare a stdout logger in my log4j.properties file ? Something like _log4j.logger.stdout = INFO, outAppender_ ? Just to be sure that we don't loose logs and to locate System.out calls in order to remove them.

Comment: Probably not. JBoss EAP replaces `System.setOut()` and `System.setErr()` with streams backed by a logger. This is in case someone writes to one of those streams and the console stream is discarded.

Answer (score 1):

If you include a `log4j.proeprties` file in the `WAR/WEB-INF/classes` or `EAR/META-INF` it should just work. If you're seeing application specific logging in all places then my guess would be you have a console appender configured in your `log4j.properties` file.

Comment: After removing the console appender in my log4j properties file, it still does not work. Any ideas ?

Comment: Is it a WAR or EAR deployment? Are you using log4j as your logging framework?

Comment: It's an EAR deployment. Yes, we are. We use log4j with an home-made logging layer, which call log4j logging methods with additional log information aggregation.

Comment: Don't understand why but log4j also logs in stdout so JBoss Logging catch these logs and processes them again by appending them in JBoss console and server.log like this : `INFO  [stdout] <<My log4j log message>>`

Comment: So if you see the `[stdout]` logs and are using a `ConsoleApppender` then it looks like JBoss EAP is seeing your logging configuration. JBoss EAP does wrap `stdout` and `stderr` in loggers.

Comment: Please see my reply.

Answer (score 1):

I have spent a few days figuring this out, and I think I have something that works.  I am using EAP 6.4.

First, the solution mentioned above about adding code to **standalone.xml** makes the output from my solution described below more easy to read in the console.  If you don't do that step, you get some extra line feeds in the console.

What I did is create a `log4j.xml` file, but I did ***NOT*** call it `log4j.xml`.  For my 2 applications, I called it `servicelog4j.xml`.  This means that JBoss will not find it.

Then when I am creating the log4j logger, I do the following (this is in a static method for my class called `Log4jLogger`):

```
public static Logger getLogger(Class aClass) {
    ClassLoader classLoader = Log4jLogger.class.getClassLoader();
    InputStream log4JStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("servicelog4j.xml");
    if (log4JStream != null) {
        new DOMConfigurator().doConfigure(log4JStream, LogManager.getLoggerRepository());
    }

    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(aClass);
    return log;
}
```

Now, the file `servicelog4j.xml` is in the resources folder of my Eclipse project, so that when the application is deployed, it will get copied to `WEB-INF/classes/servicelog4j.xml`.

The contents of that file are a standard log4j file.  I have a standard file appender and a console appender.  The file appenders for each application point to different files.

To have debugging code for just my classes appear in the console (and in the file), I place the following in `servicelog4j.xml` (since all my code is in the package `com.mycompany.mypackage`):

```
  <logger name="com.mycompany.mypackage">
      <level value="debug" />
      <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
  </logger>
  <root>
      <priority value ="info" />
      <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>
```

With the above configuration, I get all messages in the Eclipse console as well as the file.  If I just remove the `<logger>` section, then the debug messages go nowhere, which is what I'd want in production.